# Delete duplicates but keep only the last one

Tags: r

In the context of a study on statistical methods and also in the drafting of a report, I find myself confronted with a problem. I want to remove duplicates from a table by keeping only the last one.

For example, if I have :

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | F |
| 2 | H |
| 2 | F |
| 3 | H |

I want :

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | F |
| 2 | F |
| 3 | H |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you can use `duplicated` with `fromLast = TRUE`

```r
df[!duplicated(df$Var1, fromLast = TRUE), ]
#  Var1 Var2
#1    1    F
#3    2    F
#4    3    H
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Var1) %>% 
  summarise(Var2 = last(Var2))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    Var1 Var2 
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 F    
#> 2     2 F    
#> 3     3 H
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` option using `aggregate` with `tail`:

```r
df <- read.table(text="Var1 Var2
1   F
2   H
2   F
3   H", header = TRUE)

aggregate(. ~ Var1, data = df, tail, 1)
#>   Var1 Var2
#> 1    1    F
#> 2    2    F
#> 3    3    H
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>